# как обновить Qt Creator до Qt 6?

Tags: qt, qtcreator, обновление-приложений

Узнал о нововведении в новом Qt 6 (где улучшили 2d и 3d из за чего и решил установить).

И попробовал обновить (нигде не нашёл примера как это делать, а пробовал через модули, но не увидел там элемент обновления модулей)  но у меня ничего не вышло, можете пожалуйста подсказать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

в общем обновить не вышло :(

решил пока просто установить qt6
по этому видео

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nscgFv4l53w

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Не считаю полноценным ответом больше как комментарий*